# datetimepicker from one month to another month

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetimepicker, monthcalendar

```
SELECT * 
FROM   itemswork 
WHERE  e_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' 
       AND i_start_date BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' AND 
                                '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "'
```

The above is my sql query.  I am facing problem in datetimepicker.  When I asked for it calender wise, ( ie. from 10th July 2014 to 20th July 2014) it works, but when the date overlaps from one calender month to another calender month for example 15th June 2014 to 31st July, 2014 it does not show the list.

Comment: I suspect that the BETWEEN clause is comparing string data instead of date values.  What is the data type for i_start_date?  And, can you provide example values (the exact text value) for dateTimePicker1.Text and dateTimePicker2.Text?

Comment: Your SQL statement is fine as an example to present your problem.  However, if this is going to be production code, it is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: i_start_date is in varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Assuming datatype for i_start_date is DATETIME we need to add a day, if datatype is DATE then do not add the day as shown in the last line.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   itemswork 
WHERE  e_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' 
       AND i_start_date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "') AND DATEADD(d,1,CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "'))
```

Comment: Now This Error is showing, when I pasting your coding in my query...........     "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."